# How to find max pixel value in a bounding box on cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a `cv::Mat` m with single channel, and `cv::Rect b`, `b` is a bounding box on `m`, how to find the max pixel value inside b in C++?

Comment: How you define a max pixel value? A pixel usually has more than one values. In case you 're talking about single channel images (grayscale), do this: `double min, max; cv::minMaxIdx(m(b), &min, &max);`

Comment: Single channel it is, just update the question. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a `cv::Mat` single channel image `m` and a `cv::Rect` box `b`, you can get the min and max values using `cv::minMaxIdx()` like this:

```
double minValue, maxValue;

cv::minMaxIdx(m(b), &minValue, &maxValue);
```